# Javascript Buttons on Condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button, conditional-statements

I have an issue which I am hoping you can help with

I have a condition trap that checks the value of an element and does something depending on the value as below

```
 var dropDown = document.getElementById("myStyle");

  if(dropDown.value == "value1"){
    alert("Do Something");
  }
  if(dropDown.value == "value2"){
    alert("Do Something Different");
  }
```

this works fine and does different things depend on value of dropDown

What I want is if dropDown = value one then I want it to create a certain amount of buttons and if it = value2 it creates a different amount of button

i have tried the following

```
 var dropDown = document.getElementById("myStyle");

 if(dropDown.value == "value1"){
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
    btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
    document.body.appendChild(btn);   
  }
 if(dropDown.value == "value2"){
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON1");        // Create a <button> element
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME1");       // Create a text node
    btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
    document.body.appendChild(btn); 
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON2");        // Create a <button> element
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME2");       // Create a text node
    btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
    document.body.appendChild(btn); 
  }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and doesn't create any buttons in either condition

Any Ideas where I'm going wrong basically I'm trying to create the equivalent of

```
<button type="button" onclick="small('MEDIUM')" id="select_imc">M</button>
```

OR

```
<button type="button" onclick="small('SMALL')" id="select_imc">S</button>
<button type="button" onclick="small('MEDIUM')" id="select_imc">M</button>
```

Depending on the condition

Any help is appreciated

Mark

Comment: *"doesn't create any buttons in either condition"* - The code shown works for "value1": https://jsfiddle.net/bo4w6jfd/ (but if you want this to happen in response to the user selecting a value you'll need an event handler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing called `"BUTTON1"` that you can create inside DOM.

```
document.createElement("BUTTON1");
```

you need to specifically pass the tag name.There is no html element called `BUTTON1`.Inisde the condition `dropdown.value == 'value2'` use the following.Just pass the valid tag name which is `'BUTTON'`

```js
var dropDown = 'value2'

if(dropDown == "value2"){
        var btn = document.createElement("button");        // 
        var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME1");       
        btn.appendChild(t);                                
        document.body.appendChild(btn); 
        btn = document.createElement("button");        
        t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME2");       
        btn.appendChild(t);                                
        document.body.appendChild(btn); 
      }
```

Comment: Hi there Sorry my fault I put Button 1 & 2 Just to show its 2 sperate button I had already tried what you put and get the same result no buttons

Comment: then check if dropdown.value has a valid value or not?  if code execution enters into the second if block, then it should create the button

Comment: Hi There I have checked it and the condition works fine if the value is 1 it goes to the 1 code and if the value is 2 it goes to the 2 value I have put different alert message in each and it shows the correct message so I know that part is working

Comment: Are you expecting the buttons to change when you change the dropdown?

Comment: if i put <button type="button" onclick="small('SMALL')" id="select_imc">S</button> outside the script it draws the button

Comment: is this the actual code? supply your real button creation code instead of the mock up code

Comment: im not yet i want to get the button drawing first before I move on to that is that wrong?

Comment: check the code snippet i provided in my answer.Run it. it's actually creating the buttons. Your code is fine.

Comment: your absolutely right if I run in a blank document it works fine it must be something stopping it in the rest of my code which is a form. ill have to see if I can find whats causing it thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

```
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("myStyle");
var selectedDDVal = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;

if(selectedDDVal == "value1"){
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
  var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
  btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
  document.body.appendChild(btn);   
}

if(selectedDDVal == "value2"){
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON1");        // Create a <button> element
 var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME1");       // Create a text node
 btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
 document.body.appendChild(btn); 
}
```

Comment: document.createElement("BUTTON1"); is not a valid html tag to create

Comment: erm? Did you post this by mistake?

Comment: Hi Jeet Again thanks for this But I still Get No Button

Comment: Also While the element is a drop down datalist I need to be able to check based on the String Contents of the elemnet This part works fine its the button code that doesnt